# how to create picture comment with picture scale url using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to attach a picture comment to a cell in excel using vba that aspect ratio of commentbox matched with the picture dimensions. the following vba code works but has the problem yet.

```
Sub setPic(ran As Range, URL As String)
    Dim CommentBox As Comment
    Set CommentBox = ran.AddComment
    'Remove Any Default Comment Text
    CommentBox.Text Text:=""

    'Insert The Image and Resize
    CommentBox.Shape.Fill.UserPicture (URL)

    'not like this:
    'CommentBox.Shape.ScaleHeight 6, msoFalse, msoScaleFormTopLeft 
    'CommentBox.Shape.ScaleWidth 4.8, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
End Sub
```

After I set a picture comment

I tried manually: "right click on cell" > edit comment> "right click on border of comment box" > format comment > Colors and Lines tab > color > fill effects > picture > check lock picture aspect ratio

click ok, click ok

then again in format comment:

.. > format comment > size tab > click on "Reset"

click ok

it works but I want the vba code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to use

```
CommentBox.Shape.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
```

Comment: this is not for the picture (format comment > size tab > lock aspect ratio);
I think it must be in the CommentBox.Shape.Fill.